# Grindstone replacement for Mac

Tags: osx, time-management, productivity

I am using [Grindstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindstone_%28time-tracking_software%29) (from Epiforge) for time tracking and I am very pleased with it. It has great idle detection.

Soon I will start working on Mac and so I'm looking for a grindstone replacement (Grindstone works only on Windows). Any idea?

Minimum functionality:

1. IDLE detection
2. Task renaming
3. Task merging
4. Task grouping by the client or by the project or by the category